# Any change to my hard disk is ignored after shut down

Tags: windows-8, ssd

I have a strange problem with my computer.
When i try to create a file (anywhere on my hard disk):

1. File is created
2. I can see the file or rename it
3. I turned off my computer and turn it on again
4. The file is not there and deleted

When i try to remove an existing file from my computer (anywhere on my hard disk):

1. I can delete the file successfully
2. I turned off my computer and turn it on again
3. The file is still there

I can not even uninstall any software from my computer or install new software on it. Also i am using Mozilla Thunderbird to manage my emails and my email disappear every time i shut down my computer.

At all, any change to my hard disk is ignored after shut down!!!
Please help me.

My computer is:

- Type: Dell Vostro 1500 Laptop
- OS: Windows 8 Enterprise
- H.D.D: Solid State Drive (SSD)

Comment: First guess is a virus. Run a couple of deep scans with various anti-virus software. I use Microsoft Security Essentials and Malewarebytes.

Comment: Do you use any 'deep freeze' like software?

Comment: I was scanned my computer with Microsoft Security Essentials and there is no virus. And I don't have any 'deep freeze' like software.

Comment: I have had Malewarebytes find stuff that MSE missed, although that was some time ago. :http://www.malwarebytes.org/lp/malware_lp/?gclid=CLmBkZXPyrUCFexaMgodd1MAow

Comment: Some sort of bug in the disk cache.  Basically the shutdown logic isn't doing it's job and nothing gets flushed.  (Keep in mind that the system avoids writing intermediate results to the SSD drive to not "wear it out".)  This may be exacerbated by a journalling mechanism that restores the old data when it's not told the "transaction" is complete.

Comment: (I seriously doubt that a virus is involved.  However, I can't offer any suggestion to fix things other than to try reinstalling your SSD drive driver, and maybe look over its settings.)

Comment: I'm going to agree with @DanielRHicks.  Did the laptop come with an SSD, or did you install that afterwards?  I would check that your drivers are up to date (especially if you installed the SSD yourself or reloaded the OS) and ensure that you're shutting your machine down properly.

Comment: I’m curious to learn what would happen if you create hundreds or thousands of files, preferably largish ones (presumably using some sort of script), then go get a cup of coffee (or maybe lunch and/or dinner), and then come back and **shutdown the computer** (I hope you are shutting the machine down cleanly and not just “turning it off”) and reboot.  If some of the files are there, then it might be a bug in the disk cache.  If none of them are there, then maybe you have a virus.  Or maybe the OS believes that *you* are a virus, and is rolling back the “damage” that you are causing.

Comment: Dear Scott, I was tested what you suggest and files was deleted. Virus scanning with some sort of scanners could not find any virus. I'm trying to update my hard disk driver.

Comment: Do double-check the "Policies" settings for the drive in Device Manager.  I'm not sure what buttons might be there for an SSD, but there may be an obvious setting problem.

Comment: I was tried so many things like Virus Scan, Check Disk, Copying big files, even formatting my hard using another computer but nothing worked. Even after normal formatting, all of my data was there and formatting was not effective. At last, I had to low level format my hard disk and now everything is ok.